# Ajax calls PHP file but PHP file doesn't return

Tags: php, ajax

I am making an ajax call in a file called level1_1.php that posts to validate1_1.php (attached below). However, what happens is that the user gets redirected to validate1_1.php which simply prints to the screen the string (either "CORRECT", "INCORRECT", or "NOLIVES") that I want to be passed into the callback function that makes up the third parameter of my $.post call. How do I return back to level1_1.php from validate1_1.php??

level1_1.php:

```
session_start();
<h5>Type answer here: </h5>
<form>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="userinput"></textarea>
    <span> <?php echo $msg;?></span>
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.post("validate1_1.php",
    {
        userinput: $("#userinput").val;
    },
    function(data){
        if (data == "CORRECT")
        {
            alert("Good job! Get ready for the next level!");

            // take user to next level
            window.location.replace("game.php");
        }
        else if (data == "INCORRECT")
        {
            alert("Sorry, that is incorrect. You have lost a life.");
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect user to game over screen  
            window.location.replace("gameover.php");
        }
    });
});                              
</script>
```

validate1_1.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $msg = "";
    $userinput = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST["userinput"]);

    // if incorrect, lose life
    if (strcasecmp($userinput, $_SESSION["ptext"]) != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["lives"]--;

        $msg = "INCORRECT";

        // if no more lives, game over!
        if ($_SESSION["lives"] == 0)
        {
           $msg = "NOLIVES";
        }

    }

    // otherwise, move on to next level
    else
    {
        $msg = "CORRECT";
    }       

    echo $msg;      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the below line

```
userinput: $("#userinput").val;
```

to

```
userinput: $("#userinput").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes. If you still have problems, use your browser's debugging tools to help.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    // 1. prevent your submit button from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("validate1_1.php",
    {
        // 2. you're using 'name' attribute not 'id' attribute
        // 3. val() not val
        userinput: $("[name=userinput]").val(); 
    },
    function(data){
        if (data == "CORRECT")
        {
            alert("Good job! Get ready for the next level!");

            // take user to next level
            window.location.replace("game.php");
        }
        else if (data == "INCORRECT")
        {
            alert("Sorry, that is incorrect. You have lost a life.");
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect user to game over screen  
            window.location.replace("gameover.php");
        }
    });
});
```